# Python: How to filter columns with a character included but not multiple characters included

Tags: python, regex

I have a dataframe with column names that include `*` or `**`, like below.

```
data = [['Tom', 'M', 10], ['Nick', 'M', 15], ['Ann', 'F', 14]] 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name*', 'Gender**', 'Age'])
```

I wanted to only filter columns that had one `*` but not two `**` (so only `Name*` would be left in this case). But if I use `df.filter(regex="\*")`, it leaves both `Name*` and `Gender**`. How do I tell `regex` to only look for one `*` and not `**`?

Comment: Perhaps `df.filter(regex="\w\*$")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `^[^*]*\*[^*]*$` to match strings with exactly one asterisk. `[^*]*` matches 0 or more characters that aren't `*` literals, followed by a `*` literal, followed by `[^*]*` again, anchored on both ends.

```
>>> data = [['Tom', 'M', 10], ['Nick', 'M', 15], ['Ann', 'F', 14]]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name*', 'Gender**', 'Age'])
>>> df
  Name* Gender**  Age
0   Tom        M   10
1  Nick        M   15
2   Ann        F   14
>>> df.filter(regex=r"^[^*]*\*[^*]*$")
  Name*
0   Tom
1  Nick
2   Ann
```

While this is a very literal interpretation of your request, `\w\*$` might be plenty accurate for your use case, as Nick points out in the comments (although be warned, it'll match something like `"*foo*"`).

Another option could be `^[^*]*\*$` which is the same as my original proposal but with the asterisk at the end of the string only.